# Do any Christian denominations or groups teach about Satan's common tactics to pierce through the spiritual armor of a Christian?

Tags: soteriology, satan, denomination-survey, ephesians, spiritual-warfare

In Ephesians 6:10-20, the apostle Paul teaches an important mystery: all Christians are in spiritual warfare against invisible evil forces from the kingdom of Satan. And just like soldiers have to wear armors for protection in the natural realm, Christian are to put on the whole armor of God so they may have complete protection in the spiritual realm.

> 10 Finally, be strong in the Lord and in the strength of his might. 11 **Put on the whole armor of God, that you may be able to stand against the schemes of the devil**. 12 **For we do not wrestle against flesh and blood, but against the rulers, against the authorities, against the cosmic powers over this present darkness, against the spiritual forces of evil in the heavenly places**. 13 Therefore **take up the whole armor of God**, that you may be able to withstand in the evil day, and having done all, to stand firm. 14 Stand therefore, having fastened on the belt of truth, and having put on the breastplate of righteousness, 15 and, as shoes for your feet, having put on the readiness given by the gospel of peace. 16 In all circumstances take up the shield of faith, with which you can extinguish all the flaming darts of the evil one; 17 and take the helmet of salvation, and the sword of the Spirit, which is the word of God, 18 praying at all times in the Spirit, with all prayer and supplication. To that end, keep alert with all perseverance, making supplication for all the saints, 19 and also for me, that words may be given to me in opening my mouth boldly to proclaim the mystery of the gospel, 20 for which I am an ambassador in chains, that I may declare it boldly, as I ought to speak. [Ephesians 6:10-20, ESV]

A Christian covered in the full armor of God must be like a spiritual tank, capable of wreaking tremendous havoc in the kingdom of Satan. And as an expert military strategist, I would expect Satan to have special tactics in place to target those Christians who are particularly dangerous to his kingdom, in order to make them stumble.

Do any Christian denominations or groups dig deep into this topic? Do any Christian congregations teach about the different tactics that Satan and his kingdom may employ to pierce through the spiritual armor of a Christian? Is this even possible to begin with? And in a hypothetical worst case scenario, could the armor of a Christian end up so broken and pierced that even their salvation might be in danger?

Comment: Catholics and Orthodox would say that a person can give up their salvation (though they might discuss it in different ways). Not all Protestants would agree.

Comment: Resisting temptation and strengthening virtue is called asceticism; as far as ascetical treatises are concerned, the (Egyptian) [Patericon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patericon), the [Sayings of the Desert Fathers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophthegmata_Patrum), and the [Leimonarion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Moschus) (Spiritual Meadow) come to mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question says "*to pierce through the spiritual armor*".

I would suspect that such protection *can't* be pierced (why would God provide inadequate equipment to "*be able to withstand*"?).

The real issue happens when people let down their guard, allowing Satan to *get past* their armor.

---

Here are a couple of examples of denominations that consider Satan to be a very significant force that every Christian should be concerned about.

---

The United Church of God publishes much material on the subject of Satan influence, such as:

> How does he do it? Your Bible says, "you once walked according to the course of this world, according to the prince of the power of the air, the spirit who now works in the sons of disobedience." (Ephesians 2:2)
>
> Satan's responsible for a spiritual broadcast to sway our minds.
> Imagine it this way: the airwaves are saturated with TV and radio signals that can be tuned in with electronic receivers.
> In a similar way, it's also saturated with Satan's spiritual broadcast.
> That broadcast of selfishness and wrong attitudes.
> His conspiracy is to contaminate your mind into rejecting God and His law.
> Under Satan's influence, humanity has rejected God's guidance and built this world on the wrong foundation.
>
> The spiritual conspiracy of Satan and his demons is multifaceted.
> He has many strategies, many schemes, and many devices to deceive you.
> Remember, the devil deceives the whole world! (Revelation 12:9) That means people of every nation.
> That means you and me.
> I have been deceived.
> You've been deceived.
> — [Spiritual Conspiracy [Transcript] | United Church of God](https://www.ucg.org/beyond-today/beyond-today-television-program/spiritual-conspiracy)

and:

> One of the devil’s main tools, both outside the Church and especially inside the Church, is gossip.
> Any of us can so easily become guilty of gossip.
> Idle talk often degenerates into gossip.
> Furthermore, the information passed on does not have to be false to be gossip.
> Even truth, especially in a negative light, is gossip.
> — [Tool of the Devil | United Church of God](https://www.ucg.org/beyond-today/tool-of-the-devil)

Other sermons and articles from that site include titles such as:

- Satan's Secret Weapon: The Weaponizing of Fear
- Temptation: Satan's Weapon of Mass Destruction
- Satan's Clever Tactics

A family Bible study is available: [The Armor of God: Overview](https://www.ucg.org/members/family-study-guides/the-armor-of-god-overview)

---

The Philadelphia Church of God has much stronger views about Satan's direct influence on world politics:

> … like Satan, who appears as an angel of light (2 Corinthians 11:14).
> He is deceitful and duplicitous, skilled at presenting himself as something he is not.
> He is the father of liars and was a murderer from the beginning (John 8:44).
> When he is involved, things lead to murder if we don’t wake up and understand what is happening!
> — [America Has Been ‘Fundamentally Transformed’](https://www.thetrumpet.com/21850-america-has-been-fundamentally-transformed)

And:

> Reporter Michael Hastings published a book called Panic 2012: The Sublime and Terrifying Inside Story of Obama’s Final Campaign.
> In it, he described the intriguing personal effect that the president had on the journalists covering him on the campaign trail.
>
> In an interview about his book, Hastings told msnbc’s Martin Bashir, “But that’s the presence of Obama, even on the press corps — even on the people who follow him every day.
> When they’re near him, they lose their minds sometimes.
> They start behaving in ways that are juvenile, and amateurish, and they swoon” (emphasis mine throughout).
>
> Can you explain that? What a terrible indictment against our media! What is going on? Reporters swooning and acting like nervous teenagers around a politician — is that normal? I don’t remember ever reading anything like this in American politics!
> …
> … an indication of Satan being cast down and exerting his influence at the highest levels.
> Every decision they are making in foreign policy and just about everything else is dangerously wrong.
> And we need to prepare ourselves for more terrible decisions.
>
> America has done nothing helpful about Syria, with its witch’s brew of wmd.
> We really have done nothing in Libya — we won’t even go in and fight for our own ambassador and his American supporters.
> We won’t speak out against what’s happening in Libya.
> In Egypt, after that nation had peace with Israel for 30 years, we helped kick Hosni Mubarak off his throne, and we would not speak out against Mohamed Morsi essentially declaring himself pharaoh of Egypt and a bitter enemy of the Jewish nation.
>
> Can you explain these decisions with any logic?
>
> Many people can see that these are disastrous decisions.
> But we must understand that this isn’t simply the result of ineptitude on the part of this administration, or naivety about how the world really works.
> We are seeing the aftereffects of a calculated, aggressive, satanic attack aimed at weakening and ultimately destroying the nations of Israel, starting with the world’s most powerful nation!
>
> The more time that passes, and the shorter Satan’s time gets, the angrier he grows.
> Now he has been revealed so anybody ought to be able to see him and the crises he’s causing — especially in America, Britain and Israel, but also throughout the world!
> — [America Under Attack](https://www.thetrumpet.com/literature/books_and_booklets/1856)

Answer (score 1):

The question here is misdirected and belies ones inexperience with disciplined combat.  The point of being given tools is not to study the enemy at a distance. But rather to become as familiar, adept and clever with them as possible so than when an attack comes, we can use the appropriate piece(s) in the moment with deft skill and grace. The armor given us is not ever broken, just illused as we grow unpracticed. A sword is only as strong as the arm swinging it. A shield has a myriad of uses to those that know its heft and balance.
David used that which he knew very well to defeat Goliath, he didn't do it with long and arduous study of his foe.  But he sure made a point to learn how to use armor later in life.

The closest thing I know of to the doctrine you're asking about would be CS Lewis's  Screwtape Letters. Fascinating and timeless peek into the other camp. Nothing new under the sun.